# Bloch sphere for more than 1 qubit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Of course in general the Bloch sphere is a representation for one qubit, but what if it's a higher-dimensional system which has only two eigenvectors with non-zero eigenvalues? You should be able to represent it in its eigenbasis, and choosing the two eigenvectors to be the north and south poles of the Bloch sphere, you should be able to place the state on the Bloch sphere.

Do you lose any information when you perform this? Is it a useful approach to represent states with two eigenvectors? It lets you bring any state's density matrix to an effectively one-qubit form, so can it be treated as one qubit in this situation?

Comment: What is a "higher-dimensional system which only has two eigenvectors"? Two eigenvectors *of *what*? Every self-adjoint operator - i.e. every observable - will have as many eigenvectors as the dimension of the system/space it is defined on.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Sorry for being unclear. What I was talking about is a state which has only two eigenvectors with non-zero eigenvalues.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not clearer. A *state* is a single vector in a Hilbert space. It can't have "two eigenvectors". And eigenvectors *of what operator* are you talking about?

Comment: In general a quantum state is a density matrix. When it is pure it has one eigenvector, but when it is mixed it may have more than one eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have a relatively large Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ of dimension $\dim(\mathcal H)>2$, which may be finite or infinite, and you are interested in a subspace $\mathcal S\leq \mathcal H$ of dimension two. In that case $\mathcal S$ contains two linearly independent (and w.l.o.g. orthonormal) vectors $|u⟩$ and $|v⟩$, and every vector $|\psi⟩\in\mathcal S$ can be written as
$$
|\psi⟩=a|u⟩+b|v⟩,
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers.

This is sort of... exactly what a qubit is. Whatever the implementation, there is always an underlying space which is much bigger than the qubit space, and the challenge is to engineer interactions so that things which are put in the qubit subspace will tend to stay in that subspace. Once we do we forget about the bigger space.

So, to finish it off: you take your state $|\psi⟩$ and you force it to be normalized, and you arbitrarily impose $a>0$ to get rid of the global-phase ambiguity, and you're left with a state that you can always write down as
$$
|\psi⟩=\cos\left(\frac\theta2\right)|u⟩+e^{i\phi}\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)|v⟩.
$$
And now $\theta$ and $\phi$ are your usual Bloch-sphere coordinate angles, so you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

A general 2-dimensional quantum state, that is to say a density matrix $\rho$ admits a bloch sphere representation because it admits a decomposition into the form:

$\rho=\frac{\mathbb{I}}{2}+ \vec{r}.\vec{\sigma}$

Where $\vec{\sigma}$ is a vector of the three pauli matrices and $\vec{r}$ is a real vector. There are analogous constructions in higher dimensions employing the generalized Gell-Mann matrices, but these are not relevant here. Any rank-2 trace 1 Hermitian matrix $\gamma$ can be expressed as a 2x2 trace 1 Hermitian matrix $\rho$ direct summed with the 0 matrix:

$\gamma=\rho\oplus 0 $

$\gamma=(\frac{\mathbb{I}}{2}+ \vec{r}.\vec{\sigma})\oplus 0 $

It should be obvious from this that the representation of the quantum state as a vector in a sphere remains valid, when it is rank 2.